# How to add an external javascript library to ionic 3 typescript project

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

for an assignment we need to make a thermostat app. I would like to do this in ionic but am struggling with using the provided API right now. We have been provided an API.js file with a set of function that communicate the the server we have to get our data from. I tried to make these functions myself via a provider but because the server is returning xml data I have not been successful so far. So I wanted to use the given API.js by including it in my project but am now struggling to do that as well. So I would like to get some insight on either how to include this external API into my ionic project and use the functions that is has, or on how to use the returned xml data (show it in the app and send altered data back).

Since both files are quite large I've provided some snippets below and full files in pastebin links.

The get and put commands we can use are day, time, currentTemperature, targetTemperature, dayTemperature, nightTemperature, weekProgramState and weekProgram.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

The [API.js](https://pastebin.com/RSPbXFDW)

```
var ServerUrl = '';

Type = {
    Day : 'day',
    Night : 'night'
};

Days = {
    Monday : 'Monday',
    Tuesday : 'Tuesday',
    Wednesday : 'Wednesday',
    Thursday : 'Thursday',
    Friday : 'Friday',
    Saturday : 'Saturday',
    Sunday : 'Sunday'
};

var MinTemperature = parseFloat(5.0);
var MaxTemperature = parseFloat(30.0);
var MaxSwitches = 5;

var Time;
var CurrentDay;
var DayTemperature;
var NightTemperature;
var CurrentTemperature;
var TargetTemperature;
var ProgramState;

var Program = {};
Program[Days.Monday]    = [];
Program[Days.Tuesday]   = [];
Program[Days.Wednesday] = [];
Program[Days.Thursday]  = [];
Program[Days.Friday]    = [];
Program[Days.Saturday]  = [];
Program[Days.Sunday]    = [];

/* Retrive day program
*/
function getProgram(day) {
    return Program[day];
}

/* Sorts the heating periods (the periods when the heating is on) and merges overlapping ones
*/
function sortMergeProgram(day) {
    var program = getProgram(day);
    program.sort(function(a, b){return parseTime(a[0])-parseTime(b[0])});
    for (var i = 0; i < program.length - 1; i++) {
        if (parseTime(program[i][1]) >= parseTime(program[i+1][0])) {
            var start = (program[i][0]);
            var end = (parseTime(program[i][1]) > parseTime(program[i+1][1])) ? program[i][1] : program[i+1][1];
            program.splice(i, 2);
            program.push([start, end]);
            sortMergeProgram(day);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/* Retrieves all data from the server except for weekProgram
*/
function get(attribute_name, xml_tag) {
    return requestData(
        "/"+attribute_name,
        function(data) {
            return $(data).find(xml_tag).text();
        }
    );
}

/* Retrieves the week program
*/
function getWeekProgram() {
    return requestData(
        '/weekProgram',
        function(data) {
            $(data).find('day').each(function() {
                var day = $(this).attr('name');
                Program[day] = [];
                $(this).find('switch').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('state') == 'on') {
                        if ($(this).attr('type') == Type.Day) {
                            getProgram(day).push([$(this).text(), '00:00']);
                        } else {
                            getProgram(day)[getProgram(day).length - 1][1] = $(this).text();
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
            return Program;
        }
    );
}
```

The returned [XML data](https://pastebin.com/nrnshRwc)

```
<thermostat><current_day>Thursday</current_day>
<time>23:32</time>
<current_temperature>16.0</current_temperature>
<target_temperature>16.0</target_temperature>
<day_temperature>22.0</day_temperature>
<night_temperature>19.0</night_temperature>
<week_program_state>off</week_program_state>
<week_program state="off">
  <day name="Monday">
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="on">05:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="on">08:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="on">12:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="on">14:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Tuesday">
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create a file named `API.ts`. Inside it I would create an API class containing the properties and functions of `API.js`, correcting for Typesctipt syntax.

It also looks like whoever wrote this file wanted to also use `jquery` but it isn't imported, so I imported that too. I suppose you are given this file so make sure you place it inside `src/assets` and correct the import path in my code in order to have the matching filename.

So here's what I have for you:

```js
import * as $ from '.assets/jquery.js';

export class API {
  ServerUrl = '';

  Type = {
    Day: 'day',
    Night: 'night'
  };

  Days = {
    Monday: 'Monday',
    Tuesday: 'Tuesday',
    Wednesday: 'Wednesday',
    Thursday: 'Thursday',
    Friday: 'Friday',
    Saturday: 'Saturday',
    Sunday: 'Sunday'
  };

  MinTemperature = parseFloat('5.0');
  MaxTemperature = parseFloat('30.0');
  MaxSwitches = 5;

  Time;
  CurrentDay;
  DayTemperature;
  NightTemperature;
  CurrentTemperature;
  TargetTemperature;
  ProgramState;

  Program:any = {};

  constructor() {
    this.Program[this.Days.Monday]    = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Tuesday]   = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Wednesday] = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Thursday]  = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Friday]    = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Saturday]  = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Sunday]    = [];
  }

  /* Retrive day program
   */
  getProgram(day) {
    return this.Program[day];
  }

  /* Sorts the heating periods (the periods when the heating is on) and merges overlapping ones
   */
  sortMergeProgram(day) {
    let program = this.getProgram(day);
    program.sort(function(a, b) {
      return this.parseTime(a[0]) - this.parseTime(b[0])
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < program.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.parseTime(program[i][1]) >= this.parseTime(program[i + 1][0])) {
        let start = (program[i][0]);
        let end = (this.parseTime(program[i][1]) > this.parseTime(program[i + 1][1])) ? program[i][1] : program[i + 1][1];
        program.splice(i, 2);
        program.push([start, end]);
        this.sortMergeProgram(day);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Retrieves all data from the server except for weekProgram
   */
  get(attribute_name, xml_tag) {
    return this.requestData(
      "/" + attribute_name,
      function(data) {
        return $(data).find(xml_tag).text();
      }
    );
  }

  /* Retrieves the week program
   */
  getWeekProgram() {
    return this.requestData(
      '/weekProgram',
      function(data) {
        $(data).find('day').each(function() {
          let day = (<any>$(this)).attr('name');
          this.Program[day] = [];
          $(this).find('switch').each(function() {
            if ((<any>$(this)).attr('state') == 'on') {
              if ((<any>$(this)).attr('type') == this.Type.Day) {
                this.getProgram(day).push([$(this).text(), '00:00']);
              } else {
                this.getProgram(day)[this.getProgram(day).length - 1][1] = $(this).text();
              }
            }
          })
        });
        return this.Program;
      }
    );
  }

  /* Uploads all data to the server except for currentTemperature and weekProgram
   */
  put(attribute_name, xml_tag, value) {
    this.uploadData("/" + attribute_name, "<" + xml_tag + ">" + value + "</" + xml_tag + ">");
  }

  requestData(address, func) {
    let result;
    (<any>$).ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: this.ServerUrl + address,
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        result = func(data);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  /* Uploads the week program
   */
  setWeekProgram() {
    let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
    let program = doc.createElement('week_program');
    program.setAttribute('state', this.ProgramState ? 'on' : 'off');
    for (let key in this.Program) {
      let day = doc.createElement('day');
      day.setAttribute('name', key);

      let daySwitches = [];
      let nightSwitches = [];

      let i, text, sw;
      let periods = this.getProgram(key);
      for (i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
        daySwitches.push(periods[i][0]);
        nightSwitches.push(periods[i][1]);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Day);

        if (i < daySwitches.length) {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'on');
          text = doc.createTextNode(daySwitches[i]);
        } else {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
          text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        }
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Night);

        if (i < nightSwitches.length) {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'on');
          text = doc.createTextNode(nightSwitches[i]);
        } else {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
          text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        }
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }
      program.appendChild(day);
    }
    doc.appendChild(program);
    this.uploadData('/weekProgram', (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));
  }

  /* Creates the default week program
   */
  setDefault() {
    let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
    let program = doc.createElement('week_program');
    program.setAttribute('state', this.ProgramState ? 'on' : 'off');
    for (let key in this.Program) {
      let day = doc.createElement('day');
      day.setAttribute('name', key);

      let daySwitches = [];
      let nightSwitches = [];

      let i, text, sw;

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Night);
        sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
        text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Day);
        sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
        text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      program.appendChild(day);
    }
    doc.appendChild(program);
    this.uploadData('/weekProgram', (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));
  }

  uploadData(address, xml) {
    (<any>$).ajax({
      type: "put",
      url: this.ServerUrl + address,
      contentType: 'application/xml',
      data: xml,
      async: false
    });
  }

  parseTime(t) {
    return parseFloat(t.substr(0, 2)) + parseFloat(t.substr(3, 2)) / 60;
  }

  /* Adds a heating period for a specific day
   */
  addPeriod(day, start, end) {
    let program = this.getWeekProgram()[day];
    program.push([start, end]);
    this.sortMergeProgram(day);
    this.setWeekProgram();
  }

  /* Removes a heating period from a specific day.
     idx is the idex of the period with values from 0 to 4
  */
  removePeriod(day, idx) {
    let program = this.getWeekProgram()[day];
    let start = program[idx][0];
    let end = program[idx][1];
    program.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setWeekProgram();
  }

  /* Checks whether the temperature is within the range [5.0,30.0]
   */
  inTemperatureBoundaries(temp) {
    temp = parseFloat(temp);
    return (temp >= this.MinTemperature && temp <= this.MaxTemperature);
  }
}
```

Now in any ionic component you want to consume the API, you just import it like so:

```js
import { API } from './API'
```

and then in your code use it like so:

```js
export class yourPage {
  constructor(public api: API){}

  yourFunction() {
    this.api.setDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This seems to work perfectly!! I'm still learning a lot about typescript and your file is helping me recognize stuff tremendously!!

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon and am getting errors now.. @maninak . When importing your file with jquery.2.1.0.min.js (the jquery file we got provided) I get errors on lines 88, 91 and 92 about the property attr being non-existent and on lines 113 and 120 about the property ajax being non-existent. Could you maybe help out? The [jquery](https://pastebin.com/DsX9i240) file.

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. Jquery libraty is missing typings (everything is of type <any>) and Typescript doesn't can't match the type deductions it makes from out .ts file with the jquery file. I've updated the code above with a fix. Notice the typecasting into <any>. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks!! I had just found out about it too, now I'm getting this error when compiling: _Cannot write file '..../assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js' because it      would overwrite input file._ Any idea on how I could possibly fix that? I've put the jquery file in the assets file and the api.ts in my pages/home/ folder but when building the app that error appears.

Comment: Make sure all these files you mention are inside the `src` and not the `www` folder e.g. `src/assets/fonts`. In any case this is getting quite off topic. You should probably open a new question for that.

Comment: Everything is in scr, will open a new question though!